# SpriteKit how to display a number from NSUserDefualts first time around

Tags: sprite-kit

So im trying to show a score on a scene using NSUserDefaults using the below:

```
var savedScore: Int = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("HighestScore") as! Int
let score = SKLabelNode()
    score.text = toString(savedScore)
    score.fontName = "Menlo-Regular";
    score.fontColor = UIColor.blackColor();
    score.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width * 0.3, self.frame.size.height / 2)
    self.addChild(score)
```

But the first time this is ran, because there isn't anything in "HighestScore" yet, its crashing the app for trying to load a nil value. How can i have the score label show 0 the very first time this scene is ran, and then show whatever is in "HighestScore" every other time after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using `integerForKey:` instead of `objectForKey:` in this particular case.
Change:

```
var savedScore: Int = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("HighestScore") as! Int
```

to:

```
var savedScore = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("HighestScore")
```

That will set `savedScore` to zero if it doesn't exist in the user defaults.